# Maximal disjoint clique finding algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

I have a program which I use to find 'complete coverings' by which I mean, maximal disjoint sets of K-cliques. The K-cliques are usually generated by covering a shape with polyominoes. So I start with a shape and a set of N polyominoes, of which I need K to cover the shape. **Edit: I always choose N and K such that K is a factor of N.** I find all ways of doing this, listing a number of K-cliques, and sorting and discarding duplicates. Then I run this list through my fairly simple 'disjoint clique set finder' program. It's just a brute force greedy algorithm, as follows:

1. I count how many times each node occurs in the list of K-cliques. 'Node' means polyomino, and is represented by an integer from 1 to N. I make a "symbol list" with N lines, containing the numbers 1 to N followed by a count. Every integer is represented at least once in the list, if not I can stop looking for a maximal covering because there isn't one.
2. I sort the symbol list by count, lowest first.
3. I sort the K-clique list using the sort order defined by the sorted symbol list. First I sort the symbols (ie nodes) in each line. Then I sort the lines.
4. One last attempt to optimise 'speed to first solution': I partition the list of cliques into sections, based on the first symbol in each line. Sections may be empty, that just means that particular symbol did not occur as the least frequently occurring symbol in any clique. I then sort each section by a metric which I have varied in the past, but which is something like "the highest number of unobstructed cliques remains'. Obstructed cliques are those which have been struck out because a clique has been included already which uses a symbol in common with that clique.
5. Now I just loop over the list, each loop covers all entries in the the "next available section", which is to say the next unused symbol, in order. Since I'm searching for a maximal covering I can't skip an unused symbol.

Naturally this works just fine for small lists like 'find 11 disjoint octiamond 6-cliques from a list of 44000', and fails abysmally on things like dodecominoes.

My question is, is there a known algorithm that does a way better job finding such maximal disjoint cliques?

By way of example, here is a set of 2680 5-cliques using a set of 245 nodes. My program has spent many thousands of hours searching for a maximal set of 49 mutually disjoint 5-cliques. I have found countless sets of 48. But I still don't know whether there is a set of 49. I found this list in 2005, someone posted it as a challenge for this sort of problem, I can't remember who or where. The nodes were numbered from 0 to 244, I renumbered 0 as 245. It's in my sorted order, so you can see that the 8 least common nodes occur 6 times each. The commonest 9 nodes all occur 120 times each. I would love to know if anyone recognises the list or knows anything about it.

List of 2680 5-cliques: https://www.amazon.com.au/clouddrive/share/2iGNkZ4t8Ib2tSPFehqmX6N9OOUBj9STdQpQeltAh3n

Sorted symbol set:
https://www.amazon.com.au/clouddrive/share/U9mAIJzrwLanbHvua4lhOSc1cVInhlr2pJm3P9ljRi7

Sample set of 48 disjoint 5-cliques: https://www.amazon.com.au/clouddrive/share/XvLzynFwemjHnreVBuqX5WrvLiymGJNOepkhz9EpTaz